# Angular Material - how to customise styling

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In the Angular Material docs under the theming section it says:

> If you need more custom styling (such as layout changes including
>   padding, margins, etc) you will need to either write CSS rules with
>   custom selectors, or build a custom version of the
>   angular-material.css file using SASS and custom variables

Does anyone know of any useful guides that walk through building a custom version of the css file? Are there any tools that come with the library that allow you do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular material documentation is a little poor in this aspect, but there is an example on how [customize buttons](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/button), I didn't try it, but I believe all the elements is the same way.